# Google sheets batchupdate Invalid value error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to update a google docs sheet. The problem is it returns with error:

```
The API returned an error: Error: Invalid value at 'data[1].values[0]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "Play'n Go"

Invalid value at 'data[1].values[1]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "Play'n Go"

Invalid value at 'data[1].values[2]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "Pragmatic"
```

Here is the data logged in the batch update

```
[ [ 'Book Of Dead' ], [ 'Moon Princess' ], [ 'Da Vinci\'s Treasure' ] ]

[ [ 'Play\'n Go' ], [ 'Play\'n Go' ], [ 'Pragmatic' ] ]

[ [ '50' ], [ '60' ], [ '70' ] ]
```

I do everything correctly and it should work but it doesn't somehow.

If I remove this data and the range its supposed to be filled in in the batch update

```
[ [ 'Play\'n Go' ], [ 'Play\'n Go' ], [ 'Pragmatic' ] ]
```

It works just fine. So the data has the same form of a 2D array as the others, only difference is another range, but there should not be any problems with the range at all, it works with the other data in the same range that the supposedly faulty data isn't accepted in just fine!!!

I do not know what I am doing wrong. Data has the same form but it just simply won't accept it for whatever reason!

I am dead sure I do not do anything wrong it just isnt working somehow!!!

EDIT:

Just to be sure that you understand my problem:

Doesn't work:

```
data:[
  {range: 'title!range', values: [['Book Of Dead'], ['Moon Princess'], ['Da Vinci\'s Treasure']]},
  {range: 'title!range', values: [['Play\'n Go'], ['Play\'n Go'], ['Pragmatic']]},
  {range: 'title!range', values: [['50'], ['60'], ['70']]}
]
```

Works just fine

```
data:[
  {range: 'title!range', values: [['Book Of Dead'],['Moon Princess'],['Da Vinci\'s Treasure' ]]},
  {range: 'title!range', values: [['Book Of Dead'],['Moon Princess'],['Da Vinci\'s Treasure']]},
  {range: 'title!range', values: [['50'],['60'],['70']]}
]
```

EDIT 2: I am really desperate. I will share my code for the update function:

`vars.providers` is not working...but chanigng it to `vars.slots` is just fine. Althought look at the logs it is the same structure, different values

```
function updateTheSheet(vars) {
  let title = vars.sheet_title === undefined ? 'Kopie van Bonushunt Template' : vars.sheet_title;
  const sheets = google.sheets({
    version: 'v4',
    auth: oAuth_client
  });

  console.log(getDocsData(`${title}!C7:C`, vars.slots))
  console.log(getDocsData(`${title}!D7:D`, vars.providers))

  sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId: 'secret url',
    resource: {
      data: [
        getDocsData(`${title}!C7:C`, vars.slots),
        getDocsData(`${title}!D7:D`, vars.providers),
        ...
      ],
      valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED'
    },
    auth: oAuth_client
  }, (err, res) => {
    ...
  });
}
```

Log oputput:

```
{ range: 'Kopie van Bonushunt Template!C7:C',

  values: [ [ 'Vikings' ], [ 'Book Of Dead' ], [ 'Da Vinci\'s Treasure' ] ] }

{ range: 'Kopie van Bonushunt Template!D7:D',

  values: [ [ 'Netent' ], [ 'Play\'n Go' ], [ 'Pragmatic' ] ] }

The API returned an error: Error: Invalid value at 'data[1].values[0]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "Netent"

Invalid value at 'data[1].values[1]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "Play'n Go"

Invalid value at 'data[1].values[2]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "Pragmatic"
```

I am really questioning my sanity here right now...

Comment: Can you provide the information about ``getDocsData()``? I would like to confirm your situation in my environment.

Comment: look at the last console log above tve Errors thats what getDocsData() does: giving a range and the values.

Comment: so just return an object with the values and the range. The arrays are already 2D getDocsData doesnt do anything fancy other than putting an object together for the sheet data

Comment: Thank you for replying. In my environment, I couldn't replicate your situation. When I used your resource object from "the last console log", I could confirm that the script worked. I would like to look for the method for replicating your situation. I apologize for this situation.